# eth0 static IPV4 address not renewing

Tags: ethernet, static-ip, poe

I have 4 pis (4B 4gig) with PoE hats and connected to a Netgear switch for power and network. I have assigned static IPs from my Google Wifi router. I am only using ethernet, wlan is not defined on these hosts. All 4 machines were set up identically using Ansible. They are set up to run a docker swarm with 1 master and 3 workers.

The problem: Every 24 hours or so, some or all of them disconnect from the network. This means I cannot access them with SSH and I cannot resolve the hostnames from any other machine. I run a prometheus/grafana stack in docker and it appears that the nodes cannot contact each other either.

I am sometimes able to access them with an existing ssh console that has been left open and reset the eth0 connection using the command:

```
sudo dhclient -r eth0 && sudo dhclient eth0
```

Here's what I can see on the host when it appears disconnected:

```
pinode01:~ $ ifconfig eth0
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet6 fe80::d734:b499:13af:beab prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>
ether dc:a6:32:86:ff:c5 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 3215789 bytes 1495890733 (1.3 GiB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 1799093 bytes 471617505 (449.7 MiB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

Here's what i can see after a reboot or a manual reset:

```
pinode01:~ $ ifconfig eth0
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 192.168.86.228 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.86.255
inet6 fe80::d734:b499:13af:beab prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>
ether dc:a6:32:86:ff:c5 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 2983 bytes 682062 (666.0 KiB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 2269 bytes 657492 (642.0 KiB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

I'm not able to figure out what is causing this to happen. The only seemingly relevant lines in /var/log/syslog is this:

```
Jul 27 20:42:35 pinode01 avahi-daemon[360]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.86.228 on eth0.
Jul 27 20:42:35 pinode01 avahi-daemon[360]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.86.228.
Jul 27 20:42:35 pinode01 avahi-daemon[360]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
```

A few things I've tried with no luck are:

- Replace the switch
- Rebuild the machines with Ansible and a fresh apt upgrade
- Setting the static IP directly on the host in /etc/dhcpcd.conf

My next step will be to rebuild one of the hosts with just the plain Raspbian image and not install any software or change anything other than the 'pi' account password, then just leave it running for a few days and see if it disconnects. I'm not sure what else I can try.

Comment: Sounds like you have a very short lease time and the broadcast is not getting a renew OR the switch is loosing routing info OR you have two DHCP servers OR the switch is up the creak OR you have duplicate IPs.  The static config should have worked if the switch is OK else your config for this was wrong.

Comment: Firstly you can not set static IP on a router although you can reserve one. The problem is almost certainly not on the Pi but the router.

Comment: I also have a Windows 10 PC and an Ubuntu 18 PC, each with static IPs from the router, but neither showing this issue. I don't have duplicate IPs assigned. I'll recreate the IP reservations on the router and see. I only have 1 DHCP server (the router). The switch might be at fault, I suppose I could return it and try a different model

Comment: Testing with a plain unmodified Raspberry Pi OS is a good idea. You may consider to install on it your applications step by step. I would also use **tcpdump** on a failing RasPi to capture DHCP packages.